# Package file has a bad manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

We released an app on Android market. 
Now we released an update of this app, one of our customers encountered "package file has a bad manifest " when update, but other customers are fine.

Anyone help?

Comment: Did you increment the versionCode in the manifest?

Comment: Yes, I did. Now, I found two customer encountered this problem,may be it is related with Android os version. I test v2.2 / v2.3.6 / v4.0.3 and work fine. Thanks your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually telling them to uninstall the old version then redownload will solve this issue.

Comment: But why get this issue? And customer would give a bad review.

Comment: True. I got this on one of my apps recently. I was able to recreate the issue myself. Usually the customer had a bad internet connection while downloading the app so it was corrupted. Also it happens more often with version 1.x with the new play store.